# Facebook Connect - after login popup hangs in infinite loop

Tags: facebook

Symptom: After connect, a popup window opens and the user enters username + password. The popup turns blank and stays open.

There is no call to the login function (but a page refresh shows the cookies are set and the user is actually logged in).

I debugged the code and found that the xdcommReceiver.js file is stuck in an endless loop in the function dispatchMessage.

Further investigation shows that there is an exception happening in the line:

```
func = hostWindow.FB.XdComm.Server.singleton.onReceiverLoaded;
```

The exception is "Permission denied for http://www.example.org to get property Window.FB from http://example.org."

How do I solve it?

#### Additional information:

The site connect URL is http://www.example.org/
The page it happens on is in the format: http://www.example/org/folder/folder2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `document.domain=site.com` into the `xd_received.htm` file (it is hidden somewhere in the Facebook wiki documentation).

Answer (score 1):

This problem also happens when some JavaScript code changes the domain. For example, your page is in a.x.com. Then a script in the page does something like

```
<script>
    document.domain = "x.com";
<script>
```

Your domain is changed and this problem shows up.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have the loop problem and uses the sample code from the Facebook API developer pages, I have a tip:

I had the same problem. What I did wrong was that when I modified script to my needs, I accidentally replaced `cookie` with `_cookie` - this changed the variable "cookie: true" and made the infinite loop.

```
FB.init({appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', status: true, _cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

The line should say:

```
FB.init({appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

I hope this helps some...

Answer (score 0):

Try using xd_receiver file rather than making it available using script. Also make sure that your page is able to find xd_receiver file. To avoid any issues, you can specify full path to your xd_receiver file like so in your code:

www.yoursite.com/xd_receiver.htm

Answer (score 0):

I posted http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=201495 some days ago, and this modification is the only method I found to make it work.

By keeping the original xd_receiver.htm file, even by specifying full path, I just can't publish my website. If you see how I could configure anything (look at my post please) to make it work without modification, please tell me!